# Compute the sum of elements of an array which can be null or undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, reduce

I have the following array:

```
myData = [[2, null, null, 12, 2],
          [0, 0, 10, 1, null],
           undefined];
```

I want to compute the sum of each sub-array, so in my case the result should be an array of this form: `result = [16, 11, 0]`. This means that `null` and `undefined` to be replaced by zeros.

My approach works fine if I don't have the last element, `undefined`:

```
MyCtrl.sum = MyCtrl.myData.reduce(function (r, a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i) {
        r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
    }); 
    return r;
}, []);
```

I tried some ways to return zero if there is a `null` or `undefined` as a sub-array but I don't know how:

```
MyCtrl.sum = MyCtrl.myData.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if(a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i) {
        r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
    }); } else {
        r[i] = 0;
    }
    return r;
}, []);
```

It says that 'i' is not defined on the else branch.

Do you know any solution to this?

Comment: Is the result from the first array really 14 or should it be 16?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could map the values by checking the inner array and if it is not given, then take an array as default value.

For adding, you could use zero as default value in a reduce with zero as start value.

```js
var array = [[2, null, null, 12, 2], [0, 0, 10, 1, null], undefined],
    result = array.map(a => (a || []).reduce((s, v) => s + (v || 0), 0));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: OK, I think I prefer your answer @Nina Scholz!

Answer (score 1):

You can try (using lodash):

```
var myData = [[2, null, null, 12, 2],
          [0, 0, 10, 1, null],
           undefined];
// Flatten array
var myDataMerged = _.filter([].concat.apply([], myData), (v) => {
    return _.isNumber(v);
});

var sum = myDataMerged.reduce((a,b) => {
        return a+b;
});
console.log(myDataMerged);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about use `.map`?

```
var myData = [
    [2,null,null,12,2],
    [0,0,10,1,null],
    undefined
];

var sum = myData.map(function(item,index){
    if(!item)return 0;
    if(item.length <2)return item[0];
    return item.reduce(function(i1,i2){return i1+i2});
});;


console.log(sum);//[ 16, 11, 0 ]
```